# Google Script to format information pulled through script

Tags: google-apps-script

the following script below will read my email and pull a value from an email as well as the recipient of the message.  I'm looking to add to the code in which I just get the email address for the recipient.

Currently, the code will process: John Doe *** john.doe@gmail.com ****
- I just want the code to pull john.doe@gmail.com, without the arrow bracket symbols

Any insight on where to add this is greatly appreciated!

```
 // Modified from http://pipetree.com/qmacro/blog/2011/10/automated- 
 email-to-task-mechanism-with-google-apps-script/

// Globals, constants
var LABEL_PENDING = "example label/PENDING";
var LABEL_DONE = "example label/DONE";

// processPending(sheet)
// Process any pending emails and then move them to done
function processPending_(sheet) {

// Date format
var d = new Date();
var date = d.toLocaleDateString();

// Get out labels by name
var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);
var label_done = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_DONE);

// The threads currently assigned to the 'pending' label
var threads = label_pending.getThreads();

// Process each one in turn, assuming there's only a single
// message in each thread
 for (var t in threads) {
 var thread = threads[t];

// Gets the message body
var message = thread.getMessages()[0].getBody();
var recipient = thread.getMessages()[0].getTo();

// Processes the messages here
orderinfo = message.split("example");
rowdata = orderinfo[1].split(" ");

// Add message to sheet
sheet.appendRow([rowdata[1], recipient]);

// Set to 'done' by exchanging labels
thread.removeLabel(label_pending);
thread.addLabel(label_done);
 }
}

// main()
// Starter function; to be scheduled regularly
function main_emailDataToSpreadsheet() {
// Get the active spreadsheet and make sure the first
// sheet is the active one
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);

// Process the pending emails
 processPending_(sh);
}
```

Comment: Circling back here, I also have another error.  When the script runs, I'm receiving an error email alert which says:  


TypeError: Cannot call method "getThreads" of null. (line 20, file "Code").  From what I've read, it could be an issue with the label naming in my inbox, but it appears to be matched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your last error message:

```
var LABEL_PENDING = "example label/PENDING";
var LABEL_DONE = "example label/DONE";
```

script will search labels with the name: "example label/PENDING" and "example label/DONE". Are you sure that you have the label with name "example label/PENDING" or "example label/DONE"?

Here is a little bit modified code based on your example. You just need to create label "PENDING" and mark some messages with this label.

```
var LABEL_PENDING = "PENDING";

function processPending () {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
// Date format
var d = new Date();
var date = d.toLocaleDateString();

// Get out labels by name
var label_pending = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(LABEL_PENDING);

// The threads currently assigned to the 'pending' label
var threads = label_pending.getThreads();

// Process each one in turn, assuming there's only a single
// message in each thread
 for (var i = 0; i <threads.length; i++) {
 var thread = threads[i];

// Gets the recipient
var recipient = thread.getMessages()[0].getTo();

// Add recipient to sheet
sheet.appendRow([recipient]);

 }
}
```